# Differentiate Between Tab and Mouse Click When Entering an Object

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Is there a way to do this? I have a DataGridView named dgv1. dgv1 does not discriminate between when a user uses a mouse click or a tab to enter it under dgv1.Enter.

```
Private Sub dgv1_Enter(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles dgv1.Enter

'Whether I click or enter by tabbing, it doesn't matter. This gets triggered first before CellClick or MouseClick/MouseDown.

End Sub
```

Is there a way to make it be able to tell if I entered it using tab or a mouse click? I have a need for the datagridview to select the first row when I enter it using a tab, and select whatever row I clicked on when using a mouse.

Comment: Probably only by using (a couple of) other events that will occur soon before/after, like KeyUp or MouseDown/Up in conjunction. Maybe hook all of these events and print a message to the console so you can look at the eventing flow and see which events occur when, so you can store a class wide datetime in one event and then check it having occurred within the last few milliseconds in another event to know what to do. *tbh I would leave this alone** though; the default behaviour is what users expect and you're looking to change it - not always a good idea

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/order-of-events-in-windows-forms indicates that when mousing around the (previously selected control) fires a LostFocus early on, but this apparently doesn't occur with tabbing until later. Could be of some help, but it would be quite awkward I think

Comment: Why not make the first row the current row when the grid loses focus? That will then be the row that gets tabbed into but clicking a row will select that row.

Comment: @jmcilhinney That's actually a good alternative to the thing I'm trying to do.

Comment: I still think it should be a "if there isn't a current row, make it the first row, otherwise leave alone"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality you are seeking is defined in the [ContainerControl Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol?view=netframework-4.8).

From the ContainerControl documentation's [Remarks section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)(emphasis added):

> A ContainerControl represents a control that can function as a
>   container for other controls and provides focus management. Controls
>   that inherit from this class can track the active control they
>   contain, even when the focus moves somewhere within a different
>   container.
>
> ContainerControl objects provide a logical boundary for contained
>   controls. **The container control can capture the TAB key press and move
>   focus to the next control in the collection.**

Specifically to achieve your goal, you can override the [ContainerControl.ProcessTabKey(Boolean) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.processtabkey?view=netframework-4.8) of the nearest ancestor control of the Datagridview that is a ContainerControl; typically this will be the Form itself.

So assuming that the Datagridview is not contained in a SplitPanel or UserControl, you could add the following logic to the Form code.

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessTabKey(forward As Boolean) As Boolean
  ' call the base method to select the next control 
  Dim ret As Boolean = MyBase.ProcessTabKey(forward)

  If ActiveControl Is DataGridView1 AndAlso DataGridView1.RowCount > 0 Then
    DataGridView1.ClearSelection()
    DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0)
    DataGridView1.Rows(0).Selected = True
  End If
  Return ret
End Function
```